# NPE at intent.getStringExtra when launched from home screen

Tags: android

On some device running Android 5.0 and above, my app will crash when it's opened from home screen with the following message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.imincode.menitiplus.MainActivity.loadSelectedIntent(MainActivity.java:229)
at com.imincode.menitiplus.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:213)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2462)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2475)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2484)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

and here's the code that caused the error.

```
private void loadSelectedIntent(Intent intent){
        if ((intent != null) && (intent.getExtras() != null)){
            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentManager fManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle;
            if (intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller").equals("expensesRecurring")){
                fragment = new MenuNotifications();
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("tab", "0");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentMenuNotifications");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }else if (intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller").equals("creditCard")){
                fragment = new MenuNotifications();
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("tab", "1");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentMenuNotifications");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }else if (intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller").equals("locationAlert")){
                fragment = new MenuNotifications();
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("tab", "2");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentLocationAlert");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }

        }
    }
```

Specifically, the line that throws the error is

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller").equals("expensesRecurring"))
```

loadSelectedIntent would be called from 2 places in MainActivity.
The first one:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        loadSelectedIntent(intent);
    }
```

And the second one:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent isThereAnyIntentHere = getIntent();
        if ((isThereAnyIntentHere != null) && (isThereAnyIntentHere.getExtras() != null)){
            loadSelectedIntent(isThereAnyIntentHere);
        }
    }
```

Take note that this error would only appear when the user tries to launch the app by clicking on the app's icon on the home screen. The app can be lauched without any problem if the user clicks on 'Open App' from Play Store.

Why do this error happens only on selected devices, and only when launched from the home screen?

And I thought by putting the code

```
if ((intent != null) && (intent.getExtras() != null))
```

it surely would have made sure intent.getStringExtra isn't null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `intent.getExtras() != null` only guarantees there is some kind of extra in your intent, but that is not limited to only the extras you've set. The launch intent may contain anything.

The problem is that [`intent.getStringExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)) can return `null` if it doesn't find the extra name you were trying to find. One quick and dirt solution is to invert your `if` statement as follows:

```
if ("expensesRecurring".equals(intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller")))
```

You can also check for the nullity of your extra and then consume it as in:

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller") != null && intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller").equals("expensesRecurring"))
```

Comment: Instead of doing as you suggested, I put it further up, making it if ((intent != null) && (intent.getExtras() != null) && (intent.getStringExtra("intentCaller") != null)) . Shouldn't be a problem right? Couldn't test it now. Need to get my hands on the phone that throws this error first.

Comment: other important question is... why why why does it only happen on about 5% of the phones? The other 95% is working without ever throwing this error.

Comment: Maybe some versions of android add some kind of extra there? I ran into some spurious intent in my app and started doing extra checks because of them. Anyhow, I'm afraid I don't know enough to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

> And I thought by putting the code
>
> ```
> if ((intent != null) && (intent.getExtras() != null))
> ```
>
> it surely would have made sure intent.getStringExtra isn't null?

nope, you know that the extras bundle isn't `null` but you haven't established that the specific keys exist. [`getStringExtra` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String))

So from [`getExtras` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) we know that it will return null if there aren't *any* extras.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Upvoted your answer, but Edson Menegatti has written the answer in more details, so going to accept his answer as the right one (after I manage to test it)